# Adding together vector array functions

Tags: objective-c, arrays, math, double

This code works as intended, giving me the number from these 10 input fields. Now, I want them all added together to one number. (all the miTimesFrac results.) Any really effective way of doing this?

```
double fraction[10] = {methane, ethane, propane, nbutane, ibutane,npentane,ipentane,nhexane,nitrogen,oxygen};
double Mi[10] = {16.0426,30.064,44.0962,558.123,558.123,72.1498,72.1498,86.1766,28.0134,31.9988};
double miTimesFrac[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) miTimesFrac[i] = Mi[i] * fraction[i];
```

I've tried a few things, like this

```
double TMiTimesFrac;
for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) TMiTimesFrac = miTimesFrac[i]+miTimesFrac[i-1];
```

This returns the same value every time tho. Any functions i'm missing?

Comment: one of those basic programming idioms that you have to learn, like i=i+1. Sum = ....

Comment: I tried alot of stuff like that. Couldnt find a way to make it work. Example?

Comment: Do you want to compute the summation of all the elements in miTimesFrac?

Comment: Initialize the sum to 0. Then add each element to sum in a loop. inside the loop you'll have something like sum = sum + <...>.

Comment: In the code that you have you are using a for loop. Now for the summation you still have to use a for loop, but the operation that you do is a sum instead of a multiplication. Keep track of the sum and constantly add elements.

Comment: Yeah @RamyAlZuhouri the question is how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
double TMiTimesFrac;
for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) 
    TMiTimesFrac = miTimesFrac[i]+miTimesFrac[i-1];
```

Doesn't do the job, because you don't keep track of all the previous values of TMiTimesFrac, so that only the last value (miTimesFrac[9]+miTimesFrac[8]) contributes to the final value of TMiTimesFrac.

So first of all initialize TMiTimesFrac to zero. Then add every value to it:

```
double TMiTimesFrac= 0.0;
for(unsigned int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    TMiTimesFrac+=miTimesFrac[i];
}
```

Now you should be able to do it without pasting the code. I suggest to try it.